# Why can macOS have two files with same name?

Tags: macos, filesystem, extended-attributes

I found there are two files with same names but one with extended attribute while the other not (Actually I used `sed` command to do `in-place` operation with one file before):

```
-rw-r--r--  1 nanxiao  staff   351K Sep 28 12:29 db_chunks.csv
-rw-r--r--@ 1 nanxiao  staff   351K Sep 28 09:55 db_chunks.csv
```

So when I open `db_chunks.csv`, which file is actually operated? What is the relationship with these two files?

P.S., my macOS is Catalina.

Edit:
The following is the output of `ls -lb`:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 nanxiao  staff  538150 Sep 28 12:29 pcap_chunks.csv
-rw-r--r--@ 1 nanxiao  staff  538658 Sep 28 12:25 pcap_chunks.csv
```

And although both are `csv` files, they are classified as different file formats in Finder:
[image]

The "Get info" of both files:
[image]

Comment: the -Q agrument for ls in unix (along with -b) should quote the filename so you can see exactly what it is

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You cannot have two files with the same name in the same folder.

If you look closely at the "Get Info" screenshots you've posted - there seems to be a much larger gap between the filename and "Info" on the left-most screenshot compared to the right-most screenshot.

This seems to indicate that you've probably have a space at the end of the name of one of the files. You can just rename the file in Finder to give it a separate name and remove the space.

Comment: which is underscored by the fact that Numbers only wants to open one of the files, the filetype of the other file it not "csv", but something different.

Comment: Also, if you select the text in the `ls -lb` codeblock, you'll notice a stray space.

Comment: Another way to see this from the command line is `ls -lb | sed -nel`. Those options to `sed` make it (among other things) add a dollar sign to the end of each line, so you'll have `... db_chunks.csv$` for one file, and `... db_chunks.csv $` for the other one.

Comment: Or use the GNU tools (e.g. from homebrew): `gls` will produce `abc  'abc '`

Comment: @OldBunny2800 The codeblock does not contain an extra space, you are probably selecting the enter character on the first line, but not on the second. Press Ctrl+a and see that both selection boxes have the same length